# Is it an efficient way that pass a `connection` object between Python functions?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have been confued for a long time that how to write the most **efficient** or pythonic code to pass a database connection object, a `pymysql.connect` instance for example, between Python functions.

The following two methods are what I have tried:

#### 1. Passing the database config

Here is the example code:

```py
data_base_config = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 3306, 'user': 'root', 'passwd': '111', 'db': 'test'}

def func1(db_config):
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_config)
    # do sth


def func2(db_config):
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_config)
    # do more things

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1(data_base_config)
    func2(data_base_config)
```

#### 2. Passing the connection object

Here is the example code:

```py
data_base_config = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 3306, 'user': 'root', 'passwd': '111', 'db': 'test'}

def func1(conn):
    # do sth with conn


def func2(conn):
    # do more things with conn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_config)
    func1(conn)
    func2(conn)
```

How about the above methods? If I write codes that excuted in multi processes or threads, which one is better? Or any kind man share me a more proper way?

Comment: If you're always going to create a connection object, then it seems better to do that once in main and pass it in to the functions.

Comment: If you will deploy your code, I think by using the second one you may get a timeout from your connection since you connect once, whereas in the first way you establish a connection each time you use the function so no timeout issues.  If you will be querying the database often the first solution might be better unless you set keep alive settings and use the second method but then might overload your database during the times you don't need to query

Answer (score 1):

This is one application. Within one application for the life of it you should never make new connections for every request. It will slow down your response.

From [apache-commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)
Creating a new connection for each user can be time consuming (often requiring multiple seconds of clock time), in order to perform a database transaction that might take milliseconds

You can always use connection pooling with appropriate timeouts. Always have min connection in pool to be at least 1 or greater as per your requirement.

Assuming you are using MySQL you can use:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import pooling
try:
    connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pynative_pool",
                                                                  pool_size=1,
                                                                  pool_reset_session=True,
                                                                  host='localhost',
                                                                  database='python_db',
                                                                  user='pynative',
                                                                  password='pynative@#29')
```